# ASP.NET Core application on IIS Express 10 gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, rider

I believe I've narrowed this down to a configuration error, but I can't find *where* the error lies.

Steps to reproduce:

- created a new project in Jetbrains Rider 2020.3. ASP.NET Core Web Application, Windows authentication.
- let the new project build itself.
- try to run the application through IIS Express.

IIS Express starts, but when I navigate to the `https://localhost:XXXXX/` page, I get an HTTP 500 error.

Things I've tried:

- deleting the applicationhost.config from the .idea folder
- deleting the entire .idea folder
- deleting the contents of %home%/Documents/IISExpress/config
- deleting the %home%/Documents/IISExpress folder and allowing it to rebuild
- Reinstalling IIS Express 10
- Reinstalling the .NET Core Hosting Bundle

Nothing seems to change the result. This same method works just fine with the IIS Express setup I have at my office, but I can't go there right now. Remoting in is slow enough that it's inconvenient at best, and impractical at worst.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that there are some outstanding issues with IIS Express and Rider 2020.3, as can be seen [in issue RIDER-55665](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-55665), though unlike the user here I was unable to fix the problem with the steps provided. It seems as though rolling back from Rider 2020.3 back to 2020.2.x fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXI2B.png)I recommend you to restart the w3svc service with the following command in the console:
net stop was / y
net start w3svc

If you still have the same problem, it is better to run the application with dotnet so that it gives you more details of the problem in the console:

dotnet wNameApplication.dll

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXI2B.png)

Try changing the section in csproj (edit with a text editor)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to the following ..

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The program runs fine in dotnet; this is specifically an issue with IIS Express. Restarting w3svc has no effect.

Comment: I recommend to publish your app in debug mode. To rule out that it is the IIE.
Also edit the main answer in case it is for the InProcess/OutOfProcess